# Clickable file that adds code in terminal and runs it automatically?

Tags: command-line, drivers

As my wi-fi driver is doing a bit weird I need to add codes into the terminal everytime I restart my PC to use Wi-Fi.

I get that opening the terminal and typing in two lines of code isn't that much work, but I was kind of curious if there was a way to just be able to click on a file, and that the file would paste the codes in the terminal and run them automatically.

**EDIT :**

The codes:

```
sudo modprobe mt7630e
sudo modprobe mt76xx
```

Comment: Add your codes in `~/.profile` ..then you don't have to do anything, they will be automatically executed upon boot..

Comment: What are the two commands you have to type in?

Comment: Heemayl thanks for your answer, I get permission denied, even though i'm root

Comment: The codes: `sudo modprobe mt7630e` and `sudo modprobe mt76xx` thanks for your  comment

Comment: Probably you should have to edit your `/etc/rc.local` file to issue this commands at boot

Comment: @heemayl that won't work, the `sudo` needs a password. Your answer is, of course, the right way.

Comment: @terdon You are right..although that comment of mine was given earlier than the actual commands were given by OP. so i had gone the usual way of adding to `~/.profile` then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the commands you have provided, it is clear that you are trying to load two modules into the kernel in the runtime after just starting your computer.

This can be done easily by the `/etc/modules` file. This file is the designated place to put the modules that will be loaded into the kernel upon system boot every time.

In your case, to load the mentioned two modules use the following command:

```
printf "mt7630e\nmt76xx" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Comment: Minor nitpick, but I think `echo` is more common than `printf`.

Comment: @saiarcot895: [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/68757)